# Use Firebase query to filter data or move data manually?

Tags: firebase

To manage invites in my app using Firebase, i want to save invite objects, but how should i structure them for best performance?

Option 1: Save all invites in same ref and use a query and .indexOn rule

```
invitesRef.orderByChild('status').equalTo('pending')
```

So it will look like this:

```
-invites
  -userid
     -invite objects
```

Option 2: Save in different ref's according to invite status

```
-invites
  -userid
    -pending
      -invite objects
    -accepted
      -invite objects
    -declined
      -invite objects
    -expired
      -invite objects
```

This way i have to delete and create every time an invite changes status.

I am using AngularFire and a $firebaseArray for all pending invites.

Option 1 seems like the best option, but how will it perform with a large amount of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already made the most important choice for performance: you're storing the invites per user. Great work!

Whether to store the invites per status, depends on the number of invites you expect and how you want to display them.

If your app will display (for example) a tab for each status, then it makes sense to also store the invites for each status in a separate node. I wouldn't worry about the cost of moving the node too much in  that case.

But if your app displays the invites for all statuses in a single list, it's better to also store them in one list in the database.

If in the latter scenario you're worried about the number of invites (these must be some really popular people you're dealing with), you could consider storing them in date-range buckets.

```
-invites
  -userid
     -201512
        -invite objects for December
     -201511
        -invite objects for November
```